# how to dcast a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
  key       no      lpm
  ab_12     1       12 
  ab_12     2       11
  ab_12     3       11
  ac_12     1       12 
  ac_12     2       11
  ac_12     4       11
  ad_12     1       12 
  ad_12     2       11
  ad_12     3       11
```

My desired dataframe is following

```
  key    no_1  no_2   no_3             no_4
  ab_12  12    11     11               does not exist
  ac_12  12    11     does not exist   11
  ad_12  12    11     11               does not exist
```

I am doing folowing in pandas,but it does not give me what I needed.

```
  df= df.melt('key').groupby(['key', 'value']).unstack(fill_value='Does not exist')
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['key', 'no'])['lpm'].unstack(fill_value='Does not exist').add_prefix('no_')
print (df)
no    no_1 no_2            no_3            no_4
key                                            
ab_12   12   11              11  Does not exist
ac_12   12   11  Does not exist              11
ad_12   12   11              11  Does not exist
```

If solution not working because duplicated `key` with `no` pairs is necessary aggregate:

```
df = (df.groupby(['key', 'no'])['lpm']
        .mean()
        .unstack(fill_value='Does not exist')
        .add_prefix('no_'))
```

Or:

```
df = (df.pivot_table(index='key', 
                    columns='no', 
                    values='lpm', 
                    fill_value='Does not exist',
                    aggfunc='mean').add_prefix('no_'))
```

EDIT: For suffixes add [`add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html):

```
df = (df.set_index(['key', 'no'])['lpm']
        .unstack(fill_value='Does not exist')
        .add_prefix('no_')
        .add_suffix('_lpm'))
print (df)
no    no_1_lpm no_2_lpm        no_3_lpm        no_4_lpm
key                                                    
ab_12       12       11              11  Does not exist
ac_12       12       11  Does not exist              11
ad_12       12       11              11  Does not exist
```

Comment: Can we also add suffix in above code e.g. `no_1_lpm` ?

Comment: @Neil - yes, `.add_prefix('no_').add_suffix('_lpm')`